# Accessing Azure DevOps variable (in variable group) from PowerShell Script FILE

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a variable smtpPassword=mypassword in an Azure Devops variable group.

This prints it (albeit in *** form):

```
steps:
- powershell: Write-Host $(smtpPassword)
```

This doesn't.  Its just blank:

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
      filePath: ./script.ps1
```

```
# script.ps1
Write-Host $env:SMTPPASSWORD
```

WHY?!  I have tried everything!!!  Please help.  It works if you set the variable in the yaml file itself just not from a variable group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You'll need to map secret variable as environment variables to
> reference them in YAML pipelines.

```
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  env:
    SMTPPASSWORD: $(smtpPassword)
  inputs:
      filePath: ./script.ps1
```

This will print it as ***, see details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbash#use-a-secret-variable-in-the-ui)

Comment: Thank you!!!  Missed that in the docs.